# Regex issue after trying and failing for over an hour

Tags: regex

I have the the following regex pattern

```
/{{(?P<expression>if|IF)\s+?\(?\s+?(?P<statement>.*)\s?\)\s+?}}\s+?(?P<output>.*)\s+?{?{?(?P<statement2>else)?}?}?\s+?(.*)\s+{{endif}}/gmi
```

To match the following:

```
{{if           (\RAD\Security::Version() != 1.0          )  }}
<p>Sorry you do not have the latest version installed...</p>
{{else}}
<p>Yay</p>
{{endif}}

{{if   (\RAD\Security::Version() != 1.0          )  }}
<p>Sorry you do not have the latest version installed...</p>
<p>Yay</p>
{{endif}}
```

However for some reason one of the parenthesis and excess whitespace is somehow captured in the "statement"

It also should not care about whether or not `{{else}}` is there

All help would be great, been banging my head on this one.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH9rR3/1)

Comment: Can you please try and make your title more descriptive? Everyone here is "trying" to solve an "issue" of some kind and "failing" at it (or else they wouldn't be asking), the duration of your trying does not say anything about the problem, and the fact that this is about RegEx can be seen based on the tags and hence needn't be included in the title.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, clearly shows I've tried and the issues are only "minor" just a pain...

Comment: Are the parentheses in the `if` required or not? In your regex the left one is optional, but the right one is required.

Comment: Yes they are required, and not optional, the ?P is naming a subpattern unless you mean i forgot to allow capitalisation on the else and endiff

Comment: Try [`{{(?P<expression>if)\s*\(\s*(?P<statement>.*)\s?\)\s+?}}\s+?(?P<output>.*)\s+?{?{?(?P<statement2>else)?}?}?\s+?(.*)\s+{{endif}}`](https://regex101.com/r/zY7qB9/1). Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: In your demo, you have two different test strings.  Are they both supposed to match?  What do you expect as the output from each capture group?

Comment: very close, just also need {{else}} to be optional

Comment: not easy to parse template code (or xml-like code) efficiently and correctly with regex alone

Comment: I just need the simple things that belong in developer hands only not the public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version:

```
{{
  (?P<expression>if|IF)
  \s+\(\s*(?P<statement>.*?)\s*\)\s*
}}
\s*(?P<output>.*?)\s*
(?:{{(?P<statement2>else)}})?
\s*(.*?)\s*
{{endif}}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY8cH9/1)

You basically misused lazy quantifiers and made `(` optional, so the whitespace was matched by the `\s+?` on the right of `\(`.

The `{{else}}` part was wrong, as you made each component of this token optional independently of each other. I grouped it into a single optional group.

Also, do yourself a favor and use the `x` option for longer patterns.

Going further, I think the pattern needs some more restructuring:

```
{{
  (?P<expression>if|IF)
  \s+\(\s*(?P<statement>.*?)\s*\)\s*
}}
\s*(?P<then>.*?)\s*
(?:
  {{else}}
  \s*(?P<else>.*?)\s*
)?
{{endif}}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY8cH9/2)

Now, you're getting three capture groups: `statement`, `then` and `else`.

Comment: Hey cheers, you're right on the money however on the 2nd match `<p>Yay!</p>` should also be apart of output, is this possible?

Comment: @Zanderwar I expanded the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can use:

```
{{
(?P<expression>if) 
\s*\(\s*
(?P<statement>.*)
\s*\)\s*}}\s*
(?P<output>.*)
\s*
(?:                         # start of optional {{else}}
 {{
 (?P<statement2>else)
  }}\s*
)?                          # end
(.*)
\s+
{{endif}}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY7qB9/3), and here is a [verbose regex version](https://regex101.com/r/zY7qB9/4).

I replaced `\s+?` with `\s*` since you were looking to match optional whitespace, and I set the whole `{{else}}` part as optional using a non-capturing group with a `?` (1 or 0 times) quantifier.

Note that there is no point in using `(if|IF)` since you already have a `i` modifier that makes the pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: Could you explain what result you expect in the question itself?